# How to remove duplicate months and years from python list?

Tags: python, list

How can we remove duplicate months and years from python list? Here's my code it's not working fine. I can't think of any solution.

```
a = ['26/09/2021', '29/09/2021','26/07/2021', '29/07/2021','26/07/2021', '29/09/2021','26/07/2022', '29/09/2022']


def rdm(l):
    l = sorted(list(set(l)))
    for i in l:
        print("/".join(i.split('/')[1:3]))

rdm(a)
```

Output :

```
07/2021
07/2022
09/2021
07/2021
09/2021
09/2022
```

Required output:

```
07/2021
07/2022
09/2021
09/2022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def rdm(l):
    month_year_parts = [x[x.index('/') + 1:] for x in a]
    # alternatively, on each element you can also choose one of:
    #   x.partition('/')[-1]
    #   x.split('/', 1)[-1]

    l = sorted(list(set(month_year_parts)))
    for i in l:
        print(i)

rdm(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to remove duplicates from a list and extract months and year.

```
a = ['26/09/2021', '29/09/2021','26/07/2021', '29/07/2021','26/07/2021', '29/09/2021','26/07/2022', '29/09/2022']


def rdm(l):
    temp = []
    l = sorted(list(set(l)))
    for i in l:
        temp.append("/".join(i.split('/')[1:3]))
    temp = list(dict.fromkeys(temp))
    print(temp)

rdm(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['26/09/2021', '29/09/2021','26/07/2021', '29/07/2021','26/07/2021', '29/09/2021','26/07/2022', '29/09/2022']


def rdm(l):
    l = sorted(list(set(l)))
    arr=[]
    for i in l:
        b= "/".join(i.split('/')[1:3])
        arr.append(b)
        
    output = []
    for x in arr:
        if x not in output:
            output.append(x)
            print(x)

rdm(a)
```

You create an array where you append all your output then check for distinct ones.

Output:

> ['07/2021', '07/2022', '09/2021', '09/2022']